# How to manage Heap (Min heap) if the value of already added item changes

Tags: java, algorithm, heap, minimum-spanning-tree, prims-algorithm

I am a java developer ( but from a NON CS/IT educational background). I have developed interest in algorithms and currently I am trying to implement Prim's Algorithm for Calculating MST. This I have told in order to let you know the context but my question is independent of MST.

I have implemented my own MinHeap instead of using Java.util.PriorityQueue (although even when I changed my code and used it I was facing the same problem that I have mentioned ahead).

I add items to the heap but the value of the item deciding the comparison can change even after the items have been added in the heap. Now once the value changes the heap is not changed and hence upon removing the item I get wrong item popped out.

How to tackle this situation..

I am pasting my code for reference. I am adding items of type Vertex in my MinHeap. Each Vertex has an 'int cost' associated which is used to compare two objects of Vertex. Now I add object of Vertex in the heap and heap is adjusted as per current value of 'cost' but once an object of Vertex is added then if its cost is changed then I want help as how to adjust and get it reflected in my Heap. Please help me in this regards and also please correct me if I am going in wrong direction.

```
public class MSTRevisited {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Graph graph = new Graph(6);
            graph.addNode('a');
            graph.addNode('b');
            graph.addNode('c');
            graph.addNode('d');
            graph.addNode('e');
            graph.addNode('f');
            graph.addEdege('a', 'b', 4);
            graph.addEdege('a', 'f', 2);
            graph.addEdege('b', 'f', 3);
            graph.addEdege('b', 'c', 6);
            graph.addEdege('c', 'f', 1);
            graph.addEdege('c', 'd', 3);
            graph.addEdege('d', 'e', 2);
            graph.addEdege('f', 'e', 4);
            graph.applyPrimAlgo();
    }
    public static class Graph {
            private Vertex verticies[];
            private int maxSize;
            private int size;
            private HashMap map;
            private MinHeap Q;

            public Graph(int maxSize) {
                    this.maxSize = maxSize;
                    verticies = new Vertex[maxSize];
                    map = new HashMap(maxSize);
                    Q = new MinHeap(maxSize);
            }

            public void addNode(char data) {
                    verticies[size] = new Vertex(data, size);
                    map.put(data, size);
                    size++;
            }

            public void addEdege(char sourceData, char destinationData, int weight) {
                    int sourceIndex = map.get(sourceData);
                    int destinationIndex = map.get(destinationData);
                    verticies[sourceIndex].adj = new Neighbour(destinationIndex, weight,
                                    verticies[sourceIndex].adj);
                    verticies[destinationIndex].adj = new Neighbour(sourceIndex,weight,
                                    verticies[destinationIndex].adj);
            }

            public void applyPrimAlgo() {
                    // add all the keys to the Q

                    PrimEdege pe = null;
                    Vertex vertex = verticies[0];
                    vertex.cost = 0;
                    vertex.state = Vertex.IN_Q;
                    Q.add(vertex);
                    while(!Q.isEmpty()){
                            Vertex poppedVertex = Q.remove();
                            poppedVertex.state = Vertex.VISITED;
                            Neighbour temp = poppedVertex.adj;
                            while(temp != null){
                                    Vertex adjVertex = verticies[temp.index];
                                    if(adjVertex.state != Vertex.VISITED){
                                            if(poppedVertex.parentIndex != -1){
                                                    char source = verticies[poppedVertex.index].data;
                                                    char destination = verticies[adjVertex.index].data;
                                                    pe = new PrimEdege(source, destination, pe);
                                            }
                                            if(adjVertex.cost > temp.weight){
                                                    adjVertex.cost = temp.weight;
                                                    adjVertex.parentIndex = poppedVertex.index;
                                            }
                                            if(adjVertex.state != Vertex.IN_Q){
                                                    Q.add(adjVertex);
                                            }
                                    }
                                    temp = temp.next;
                            }
                    }

                    PrimEdege temp = pe;
                    while(temp != null){
                            System.out.print("("+temp.source+","+temp.destination+") ");
                            temp = temp.next;
                    }
                    System.out.println();
            }

            private static class PrimEdege{
                    public  char source;
                    public char destination;
                    private PrimEdege next;
                    public PrimEdege(char source, char destination, PrimEdege next){
                            this.source = source;
                            this.destination = destination;
                            this.next = next;
                    }
            }

            public static class MinHeap {
                    private Vertex[] items;
                    private int maxSize;
                    private int size;

                    public MinHeap(int maxSize) {
                            this.maxSize = maxSize;
                            items = new Vertex[maxSize];
                    }

                    public void add(Vertex item) {
                            items[size] = item;
                            heapifyAfterAdd();
                            size++;
                    }

                    private void swap(int index1, int index2) {
                            Vertex temp = items[index1];
                            items[index1] = items[index2];
                            items[index2] = temp;
                    }

                    private void heapifyAfterAdd() {
                            int currIndex = size;
                            Vertex currItem = items[currIndex];
                            int parentIndex = currIndex / 2;
                            Vertex parentItem = items[parentIndex];
                            while (currItem.compareTo(parentItem) == -1) {
                                    swap(parentIndex, currIndex);
                                    currIndex = parentIndex;
                                    currItem = items[currIndex];
                                    parentIndex = currIndex / 2;
                                    parentItem = items[parentIndex];
                            }
                    }

                    public Vertex remove() {
                            Vertex vertex = items[0];
                            swap(0, size - 1);
                            items[size-1] = null;
                            size--;
                            heapifyAfterRemove();
                            return vertex;
                    }

                    private void heapifyAfterRemove() {
                            int currIndex = 0;
                            Vertex currItem = items[currIndex];
                            int childIndex;
                            Vertex childItem;
                            int left = 2 * currIndex + 1;
                            int right = 2 * currIndex + 2;
                            if (left > size - 1) {
                                    return;
                            }
                            if (right > size - 1) {
                                    childIndex = left;
                            } else if (items[left].compareTo(items[right]) == -1) {
                                    childIndex = left;
                            } else {
                                    childIndex = right;
                            }
                            childItem = items[childIndex];

                            while (childItem.compareTo(currItem) == -1) {
                                    swap(currIndex, childIndex);
                                    currIndex = childIndex;
                                    currItem = items[currIndex];
                                    left = 2 * currIndex + 1;
                                    right = 2 * currIndex + 2;
                                    if (left > size - 1) {
                                            return;
                                    }
                                    if (right > size - 1) {
                                            childIndex = left;
                                    } else if (items[left].compareTo(items[right]) == -1) {
                                            childIndex = left;
                                    } else {
                                            childIndex = right;
                                    }
                                    childItem = items[childIndex];
                            }
                    }

                    public boolean isEmpty() {
                            return size == 0;
                    }
            }

            public static class HashMap {
                    private MapNode[] map;
                    private char[] keySet;
                    private int maxSize;
                    private int size;

                    public HashMap(int maxSize) {
                            this.maxSize = maxSize;
                            map = new MapNode[maxSize];
                            keySet = new char[maxSize];
                    }

                    private static class MapNode {
                            char key;
                            int value;
                            MapNode next;

                            public MapNode(char key, int value, MapNode next) {
                                    this.key = key;
                                    this.value = value;
                                    this.next = next;
                            }
                    }

                    public int hash(char key) {
                            return 31 * key;
                    }

                    public int getmapIndexOfkey(char key) {
                            return hash(key) % maxSize;
                    }

                    public void put(char key, int value) {
                            int index = getmapIndexOfkey(key);
                            map[index] = new MapNode(key, value, map[index]);
                            keySet[index] = key;
                            size++;
                    }

                    public int get(char key) {
                            int index = getmapIndexOfkey(key);
                            MapNode temp = map[index];
                            while (temp != null) {
                                    if (temp.key == key) {
                                            break;
                                    }
                            }
                            if (temp != null) {
                                    return temp.value;
                            } else {
                                    return -1;
                            }
                    }

                    public char[] keyset() {
                            return keySet;
                    }
            }

            public static class Vertex {
                    public static final int NEW = 0;
                    public static final int IN_Q = 1;
                    public static final int VISITED = 2;
                    private int state = NEW;
                    private int cost = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
                    private char data;
                    private Neighbour adj;
                    private int index;
                    private int parentIndex = -1;
                    public int compareTo(Vertex other) {
                            if (cost < other.cost) {
                                    return -1;
                            }
                            if (cost > other.cost) {
                                    return 1;
                            }
                            return 0;
                    }

                    public Vertex(char data, int index) {
                            this.data = data;
                            this.index = index;
                    }

                    public void addAdjacentVertex(Neighbour adj) {
                            this.adj = adj;
                    }

                    public void updateCost(int newCost, int parentIndex){
                            this.cost = newCost;
                            this.parentIndex = parentIndex;
                    }
            }

            public static class Neighbour {
                    private Neighbour next;
                    private int index;
                    private int weight;

                    public Neighbour(int index,int weight, Neighbour next) {
                            this.next = next;
                            this.index = index;
                            this.weight = weight;
                    }
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks friends for investing time to my question, but I figured that I had few mistakes in my implementation due to which I was getting wrong answer.

1. I corrected the state of the vertex when it is added to the MinHeap
2. I corrected the logic of outputting the edge of MST and I got the correct answer....
3. Most important as Suggested by Karthik (many thanks to him) to remove and re-add the item whose 'cost' changes while it being in the heap. I actually applied bubble up approach instead of removing and again adding which worked !!

After modifying above 3 points my code is working as I expect it to work.

Also @Karthik I do not have two methods for before and after remove but rather I have one for when I add an item ( in the last and I use the method heapifyAfterAdd() and other for when I remove the 1st item then I use heapifyAfterRemove() )

Please find below my code after corrections.

```
public class MSTRevisited {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Graph graph = new Graph(6);
        /*
         * graph.addNode('a'); graph.addNode('b'); graph.addNode('c');
         * graph.addNode('d'); graph.addNode('e'); graph.addNode('f');
         * graph.addEdege('a', 'b', 4); graph.addEdege('a', 'f', 2);
         * graph.addEdege('b', 'f', 3); graph.addEdege('b', 'c', 6);
         * graph.addEdege('c', 'f', 1); graph.addEdege('c', 'd', 3);
         * graph.addEdege('d', 'e', 2); graph.addEdege('f', 'e', 4);
         */
        graph.addNode('a');
        graph.addNode('b');
        graph.addNode('c');
        graph.addNode('d');
        graph.addEdege('a', 'b', 4);
        graph.addEdege('a', 'c', 2);
        graph.addEdege('b', 'c', 1);
        graph.addEdege('b', 'd', 2);
        graph.addEdege('c', 'd', 3);
        graph.applyPrimAlgo();
    }

    public static class Graph {
        private Vertex verticies[];
        private int maxSize;
        private int size;
        private HashMap map;
        private MinHeap Q;

        public Graph(int maxSize) {
            this.maxSize = maxSize;
            verticies = new Vertex[maxSize];
            map = new HashMap(maxSize);
            Q = new MinHeap(maxSize);
        }

        public void addNode(char data) {
            verticies[size] = new Vertex(data, size);
            map.put(data, size);
            size++;
        }

        public void addEdege(char sourceData, char destinationData, int weight) {
            int sourceIndex = map.get(sourceData);
            int destinationIndex = map.get(destinationData);
            verticies[sourceIndex].adj = new Neighbour(destinationIndex,
                    weight, verticies[sourceIndex].adj);
            verticies[destinationIndex].adj = new Neighbour(sourceIndex,
                    weight, verticies[destinationIndex].adj);
        }

        public void applyPrimAlgo() {
            // add all the keys to the Q

            PrimEdege pe = null;
            Vertex vertex = verticies[0];
            vertex.cost = 0;
            vertex.state = Vertex.IN_Q;
            Q.add(vertex);
            while (!Q.isEmpty()) {
                Vertex poppedVertex = Q.remove();
                poppedVertex.state = Vertex.VISITED;
                Neighbour temp = poppedVertex.adj;
                if (poppedVertex.parentIndex != -1) {
                    char source = verticies[poppedVertex.index].data;
                    char destination = verticies[poppedVertex.parentIndex].data;
                    pe = new PrimEdege(source, destination, pe);
                }
                while (temp != null) {
                    Vertex adjVertex = verticies[temp.index];
                    if (adjVertex.state != Vertex.VISITED) {
                        if (adjVertex.cost > temp.weight) {
                            adjVertex.cost = temp.weight;
                            adjVertex.parentIndex = poppedVertex.index;
                        }
                        if (adjVertex.state != Vertex.IN_Q) {
                            Q.add(adjVertex);
                            adjVertex.state = Vertex.IN_Q;
                        } else {
                            // bubble up this Node in the heap
                            Q.bubbleUp(adjVertex);
                        }
                    }
                    temp = temp.next;
                }
            }

            PrimEdege temp = pe;
            while (temp != null) {
                System.out.print("(" + temp.source + "," + temp.destination
                        + ") ");
                temp = temp.next;
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        private static class PrimEdege {
            public char source;
            public char destination;
            private PrimEdege next;

            public PrimEdege(char source, char destination, PrimEdege next) {
                this.source = source;
                this.destination = destination;
                this.next = next;
            }
        }

        public static class MinHeap {
            private Vertex[] items;
            private int maxSize;
            private int size;

            public MinHeap(int maxSize) {
                this.maxSize = maxSize;
                items = new Vertex[maxSize];
            }

            public void bubbleUp(Vertex vertex) {
                // @TODO
                int i = 0;
                for (; i < size; i++) {
                    if (items[i] == vertex) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (i < size) {
                    int currentIndex = i;
                    Vertex currentItem = items[currentIndex];
                    int parentIndex = (currentIndex-1) / 2;
                    Vertex parentItem = items[parentIndex];
                    while (currentItem.compareTo(parentItem) == -1) {
                        swap(currentIndex, parentIndex);
                        currentIndex = parentIndex;
                        currentItem = items[currentIndex];
                        parentIndex = (currentIndex-1) / 2;
                        parentItem = items[parentIndex];
                    }
                }
            }

            public void add(Vertex item) {
                items[size] = item;
                heapifyAfterAdd();
                size++;
            }

            private void swap(int index1, int index2) {
                Vertex temp = items[index1];
                items[index1] = items[index2];
                items[index2] = temp;
            }

            private void heapifyAfterAdd() {
                int currIndex = size;
                Vertex currItem = items[currIndex];
                int parentIndex = (currIndex-1) / 2;
                Vertex parentItem = items[parentIndex];
                while (currItem.compareTo(parentItem) == -1) {
                    swap(parentIndex, currIndex);
                    currIndex = parentIndex;
                    currItem = items[currIndex];
                    parentIndex = (currIndex-1) / 2;
                    parentItem = items[parentIndex];
                }
            }

            public Vertex remove() {
                return remove(0);
            }

            public Vertex remove(Vertex vertex) {
                int i = 0;
                for (; i < size; i++) {
                    if (items[i] == vertex) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (i < size) {
                    return remove(i);
                }
                return null;

            }

            private Vertex remove(int index) {
                Vertex vertex = items[index];
                swap(index, size - 1);
                items[size - 1] = null;
                size--;
                heapifyAfterRemove(index);
                return vertex;
            }

            private void heapifyAfterRemove(int index) {
                int currIndex = index;
                Vertex currItem = items[currIndex];
                int childIndex;
                Vertex childItem;
                int left = 2 * currIndex + 1;
                int right = 2 * currIndex + 2;
                if (left > size - 1) {
                    return;
                }
                if (right > size - 1) {
                    childIndex = left;
                } else if (items[left].compareTo(items[right]) == -1) {
                    childIndex = left;
                } else {
                    childIndex = right;
                }
                childItem = items[childIndex];

                while (childItem.compareTo(currItem) == -1) {
                    swap(currIndex, childIndex);
                    currIndex = childIndex;
                    currItem = items[currIndex];
                    left = 2 * currIndex + 1;
                    right = 2 * currIndex + 2;
                    if (left > size - 1) {
                        return;
                    }
                    if (right > size - 1) {
                        childIndex = left;
                    } else if (items[left].compareTo(items[right]) == -1) {
                        childIndex = left;
                    } else {
                        childIndex = right;
                    }
                    childItem = items[childIndex];
                }
            }

            public boolean isEmpty() {
                return size == 0;
            }
        }

        public static class HashMap {
            private MapNode[] map;
            private char[] keySet;
            private int maxSize;
            private int size;

            public HashMap(int maxSize) {
                this.maxSize = maxSize;
                map = new MapNode[maxSize];
                keySet = new char[maxSize];
            }

            private static class MapNode {
                char key;
                int value;
                MapNode next;

                public MapNode(char key, int value, MapNode next) {
                    this.key = key;
                    this.value = value;
                    this.next = next;
                }
            }

            public int hash(char key) {
                return 31 * key;
            }

            public int getmapIndexOfkey(char key) {
                return hash(key) % maxSize;
            }

            public void put(char key, int value) {
                int index = getmapIndexOfkey(key);
                map[index] = new MapNode(key, value, map[index]);
                keySet[index] = key;
                size++;
            }

            public int get(char key) {
                int index = getmapIndexOfkey(key);
                MapNode temp = map[index];
                while (temp != null) {
                    if (temp.key == key) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (temp != null) {
                    return temp.value;
                } else {
                    return -1;
                }
            }

            public char[] keyset() {
                return keySet;
            }
        }

        public static class Vertex {
            public static final int NEW = 0;
            public static final int IN_Q = 1;
            public static final int VISITED = 2;
            private int state = NEW;
            private int cost = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            private char data;
            private Neighbour adj;
            private int index;
            private int parentIndex = -1;

            public int compareTo(Vertex other) {
                if (cost < other.cost) {
                    return -1;
                }
                if (cost > other.cost) {
                    return 1;
                }
                return 0;
            }

            public Vertex(char data, int index) {
                this.data = data;
                this.index = index;
            }

            public void addAdjacentVertex(Neighbour adj) {
                this.adj = adj;
            }

            public void updateCost(int newCost, int parentIndex) {
                this.cost = newCost;
                this.parentIndex = parentIndex;
            }
        }

        public static class Neighbour {
            private Neighbour next;
            private int index;
            private int weight;

            public Neighbour(int index, int weight, Neighbour next) {
                this.next = next;
                this.index = index;
                this.weight = weight;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what I am talking about. You don't even need two different methods `heapifyAfterAdd()` and `heapifyAfterRemove()`. Read my answer once again.